# Is there a way of splitting values of dictionary key?

Tags: python

I have a large json file that contains information about the transfer information of ip addresses. One or more blocks within a network address can be transferred to another entity. I want to further map a transfer to individual entity it that participated in the transfer.

```
Transfers =[{
        "original_block": "87.118.128.0/18",
        "transferred_blocks": "87.118.144.0/22, 87.118.164.0/22",
        "from": "ITD Network SA",
        "to": "Bulgarian Telecommunications Company Plc.",
        "date": "16/07/2014",
        "transferType": "POLICY"
        }, {
        "original_block": "89.25.0.0/17",
        "transferred_blocks": "89.25.40.0/21, 89.25.52.0/22, 
                 89.25.56.0/21, 89.25.100.0/22, 89.25.124.0/22",
        "from": "ITD Network SA",
        "to": "Bulgarian Telecommunications Company Plc.",
        "date": "16/07/2014",
        "transferType": "POLICY"
        }, {
        "original_block": "94.155.0.0/17",
        "transferred_blocks": "94.155.104.0/21",
        "from": "ITD Network SA",
        "to": "Bulgarian Telecommunications Company Plc.",
        "date": "16/07/2014",
        "transferType": "POLICY"
        }]

with open ('Transfers','r') as t_list:#loads the json file
    dlist = json.load(t_list)
```

`for k, v in dlist:
    dlist[k] = v("transferred_blocks").split(",")`

The expected output is the following one:

```
dlist =[{
    "original_block": "87.118.128.0/18",
    "transferred_blocks": "87.118.164.0/22",
    "from": "ITD Network SA",
    "to": "Bulgarian Telecommunications Company Plc.",
    "date": "16/07/2014",
    "transferType": "POLICY"
    },{
    "original_block": "87.118.128.0/18",
    "transferred_blocks": "87.118.144.0/22",
    "from": "ITD Network SA",
    "to": "Bulgarian Telecommunications Company Plc.",
    "date": "16/07/2014",
    "transferType": "POLICY"
    }, {
    "original_block": "89.25.0.0/17",
    "transferred_blocks": "89.25.40.0/21",
    "from": "ITD Network SA",
    "to": "Bulgarian Telecommunications Company Plc.",
    "date": "16/07/2014",
    "transferType": "POLICY"
    },  {
    "original_block": "89.25.0.0/17",
    "transferred_blocks": "89.25.52.0/22",
    "from": "ITD Network SA",
    "to": "Bulgarian Telecommunications Company Plc.",
    "date": "16/07/2014",
    "transferType": "POLICY"
    },  {
    "original_block": "89.25.0.0/17",
    "transferred_blocks": "89.25.56.0/21",
    "from": "ITD Network SA",
    "to": "Bulgarian Telecommunications Company Plc.",
    "date": "16/07/2014",
    "transferType": "POLICY"
    },  {
    "original_block": "89.25.0.0/17",
    "transferred_blocks": "89.25.100.0/22",
    "from": "ITD Network SA",
    "to": "Bulgarian Telecommunications Company Plc.",
    "date": "16/07/2014",
    "transferType": "POLICY"
    },  {
    "original_block": "89.25.0.0/17",
    "transferred_blocks": "89.25.124.0/22",
    "from": "ITD Network SA",
    "to": "Bulgarian Telecommunications Company Plc.",
    "date": "16/07/2014",
    "transferType": "POLICY"
    }, {
    "original_block": "94.155.0.0/17",
    "transferred_blocks": "94.155.104.0/21",
    "from": "ITD Network SA",
    "to": "Bulgarian Telecommunications Company Plc.",
    "date": "16/07/2014",
    "transferType": "POLICY"
    }]
```

Comment: Please show us your efforts and road block.

Comment: I have made an adjustment

Comment: It gives error "too many values to unpack (expected 2)"

Answer (score 2):

Just use a list comprehension to iterate over each of the dicts in dlist, then split the ip address list under `transferred_blocks` based on `comma`, finally create a new dict from the original dict with the updated ip addr

```
res = [dict(d, transferred_blocks=ip) for d in dlist for ip in d['transferred_blocks'].split(', ')]
print (json.dumps(res, indent=4))
```

**Output**

```
[
    {
        "original_block": "87.118.128.0/18",
        "transferred_blocks": "87.118.144.0/22",
        "from": "ITD Network SA",
        "to": "Bulgarian Telecommunications Company Plc.",
        "date": "16/07/2014",
        "transferType": "POLICY"
    },
    {
        "original_block": "87.118.128.0/18",
        "transferred_blocks": "87.118.164.0/22",
        "from": "ITD Network SA",
        "to": "Bulgarian Telecommunications Company Plc.",
        "date": "16/07/2014",
        "transferType": "POLICY"
    },
    {
        "original_block": "89.25.0.0/17",
        "transferred_blocks": "89.25.40.0/21",
        "from": "ITD Network SA",
        "to": "Bulgarian Telecommunications Company Plc.",
        "date": "16/07/2014",
        "transferType": "POLICY"
    },
    {
        "original_block": "89.25.0.0/17",
        "transferred_blocks": "89.25.52.0/22",
        "from": "ITD Network SA",
        "to": "Bulgarian Telecommunications Company Plc.",
        "date": "16/07/2014",
        "transferType": "POLICY"
    },
    {
        "original_block": "89.25.0.0/17",
        "transferred_blocks": "89.25.56.0/21",
        "from": "ITD Network SA",
        "to": "Bulgarian Telecommunications Company Plc.",
        "date": "16/07/2014",
        "transferType": "POLICY"
    },
    {
        "original_block": "89.25.0.0/17",
        "transferred_blocks": "89.25.100.0/22",
        "from": "ITD Network SA",
        "to": "Bulgarian Telecommunications Company Plc.",
        "date": "16/07/2014",
        "transferType": "POLICY"
    },
    {
        "original_block": "89.25.0.0/17",
        "transferred_blocks": "89.25.124.0/22",
        "from": "ITD Network SA",
        "to": "Bulgarian Telecommunications Company Plc.",
        "date": "16/07/2014",
        "transferType": "POLICY"
    },
    {
        "original_block": "94.155.0.0/17",
        "transferred_blocks": "94.155.104.0/21",
        "from": "ITD Network SA",
        "to": "Bulgarian Telecommunications Company Plc.",
        "date": "16/07/2014",
        "transferType": "POLICY"
    }
]
```

Comment: Worked well. Thank you